# How to add CSS to "not the first" rendered Styled Component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components

I've got a component with some pretty unique styling. The component basically renders horizontal rows (with 2 inputs, and an icon: `StyledButton` with a `Message` (remove)).

The component allows users to add/ remove as many rows as they wish, but I want to directly target any instance of the `StyledButton` that isn't the first one. I've tried the commonly suggested answers but the issue may be the fact that the entire component is being rendered each time and the CSS can't reach that far.

Any suggestions would be great.

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  margin-top: 14px;
`;

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {objects.map((enteredObject, index) => (
        <RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider
          form={form}
          object={enteredObject}
          key={`${enteredObject.key}-${enteredObject.repeatIndex}`}
        >
          <StyledHorizontalAttributes className="attributeset-row">
            {enteredObject.attributeCollection.questions
              .filter(filterRepeatAttributes)
              .map((attribute) => (
                <Fragment key={attribute.key}>
                  {renderAttribute(enteredObject, attribute, formLayout)}
                </Fragment>
              ))}
            <StyledButton
              type="link"
              buttonStyle="LINK"
              name="delete"
              dataId={`delete-${enteredObject.key}-${index}`}
              isOberonIcon
              isIconButton
              icon="bin"
              onClick={() => onRemove(enteredObject)}
            >
              <Message id="Form.Button.Remove" defaultMessage="Remove" />
            </StyledButton>
          </StyledHorizontalAttributes>
        </RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const StyledHorizontalAttributesTable = styled(StyledHorizontalAttributes)`
  & + & {
    .remove-btn {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  }
`;
```

worked using the above thanks to this answer: [Specific targeting of CSS classes with Styled Components not being rendered - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051590/specific-targeting-of-css-classes-with-styled-components-not-being-rendered-re)

Answer (score 0):

`:not(:first-child)` should work.

```css
.attributeset-row .button:not(:first-child) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "attributeset-row">
  <div class="row">One</div>
  <div class="row">Two</div>
  <div class="button">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, not sure if it's down to this being StyledComponents and not vanilla CSS/HTML - but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Lots going on, but: 
StyledContainer > 
StyledHorizontalAttributes 
> Row = Row = Button

Comment: Hard to format on comments, but both Rows sit on the same level as Button. Which are children of StyledHorizontalAttributes which is a child of StyledContainer

Comment: Sorry - are you trying to specially style the <StyledButton> when it isn't the first child of <StyledHorizontalAttributes>?

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained the problem well enough. I am trying to target any instance of <StyledButton> that isn't the first. The reason I think this may be proving difficult is because there is only ever going to be one <StyledButton> within <StyledHorizontalAttributes> component - but <StyledHorizontalAttributes> can be rendered many times with a <StyledButton> within that. Does that make sense? I appreciate you taking the time to help, it's been an issue I've been struggling with for a while.

Comment: The `:first-child` selector is only checks the parent container.  So multiple <StyledHorizontalAttributes> would make no difference.  A CodePen would be great.

Comment: This codepen doesn't obvs reflect the true syntax too well because it's not styled components etc, but it shows the way the markup could look (roughly):
https://codepen.io/simoncunningham/pen/YzQWmZV

Comment: So in the code pen example, I want to target the button in components 2 & 3 effectively

Comment: Apply the `:not(:first-child)` selector to .styled-container then - as that's what you're counting: https://codepen.io/quasipickle/pen/NWgRKzG?editors=1100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236749/discussion-between-sicun-and-quasipickle).